# Are two classes defined with the same sequence of tokens but having different underlying types breaking the one definition rule?

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

According to the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule), there can be two definitions of the same class if a list of constraints are respected.

Let's consider this header file:

```
#ifdef VAR
typedef int int_t;
#else
typedef int* int_t;
#endif

class C {
    public:
        int_t i;
};
```

All the source files that will include this header file will define the class `C`. The definition of this class will consist of the same sequence of tokens in every translation units. However, the underlying type of the member `i` is not the same depending on how the type `int_t` has been declared.

If I take the list of the constraints from cppreference.com, it seems that this code is respecting the One Definition Rule. But, I does not make sense to me because the `C` object in a program may represent different data.

Is this code breaking the One Definition Rule? If yes, which part of the ODR? If no, is this code problematic in some way?

Comment: As long as all the code that includes this header file in the project has VAR defined or VAR not defined, it does not violate ODR.  If some of the translation units have VAR defined, and other translation units do not have VAR defined, then the program will violate ODR.

Comment: Yes they do. https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#14.5

Comment: I think you're describing the entire purpose of template classes.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit If I correctly understand, when it is said "name lookup from within each definition finds the same entities", this does not refer to variables only (`i` in my example) but also the every types (`int_t` in my example). Is that correct?

Comment: If `int_t` is different then the class isn't defined by the same tokens

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am surprised because it seems to me that a token "identifiers, keywords, literals, operators, and other separators". Therefore, when we talk about a "token", we do not refer to what this token represents, right?

Comment: The word "entities" refers to entities in general, not to any specific kind of those (such as variables). A type is an entity.